# Addition of floating point, Why the First code work

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy

Why body of `if()` in 1st code Executes While the body of `if()` in 2nd code Doesn't Executes

[Float are not precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

> Working

```
double num1 = 0.2;
double num2 = 0.2;
double num3 = num1 + num2;
if (num3 == 0.4)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1st");
}
```

> Not Working

```
double num1 = 0.1;
double num2 = 0.2;
double num3 = num1 + num2;
if (num3 == 0.3)
{
    MessageBox.Show("2nd");
}
```

Comment: run !!! run away ! :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken ?

Comment: That's how floating point numbers work - it's part of their definition. They aren't precise and operations can introduce rounding errors. Check [the Wikipedia article on floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) for example. If you want accuracy, use `decimal`

Comment: I Read t already...But how the second Could possibly work

Comment: If you read it, the answer is there. Floating points are not precise. There is always a chance of errors. Never check for equality with floats or doubles.

Comment: Exectally...Float are not precise then why Body of First code is executs

Comment: You *may* get an error, it doesn't always occur. More detailed explanations can be found in coursebooks, tutorials, the Wikipedia article I linked etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried 70's time never get error...That's why i post this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reason

Machine uses binary language When it convert **number into binary , convert back into decimal The value get changed** ,due to some number can't be converted Completely in binary

When you convert `0.1 into base 2 (binary)` you get a repeating pattern after the decimal point,

Like **1/3 in base 10** ; `1/3=0.333333333333333333333333333333333..........` & never get Exact value

Therefor you can't Get every number's exact Value using normal floating point methods.

> Example (Conversion Pattern)

**0.1 Pattern In Binary...**

[image: Binary Pattern of 0.1]

[**Source:** Why 0.1 Does Not Exist In Floating-Point](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)

**0.1 Conversion** `0.1 is one-tenth, or 1/10. To show it in binary` You can See `100` is repeating after intervals As Giving output as `1001` as Shown In Diagram

[image: Conversion Of 0.1 to binary]

[**Source:** Why 0.1 Does Not Exist In Floating-Point](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)

> Second Code Snippets {Answer of 0.1+0.2 Is not Same as actual value of 0.3}

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Actual {Answer of 0.1+0.2 Is not Same as actual value of 0.3}
--------------------------------------------------------------
0.1=0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
0.2=0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
0.3=0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875

==============================================================
 Calculation 0.1 + 0.2
______________________________________________________________ 
 0.1=0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
+0.2=0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
--------------------------------------------------------------
 0.3=0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125

==============================================================
Answer
--------------------------------------------------------------
  0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
!=0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

> First Code Snippets {Answer of 0.2+0.2 Is Same as actual value of 0.4}

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Actual {Answer of 0.2+0.2 Is Same as actual value of 0.4}
---------------------------------------------------------------
 0.2=0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
 0.2=0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
 0.4=0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625  
==============================================================
 Calculation 0.2 + 0.2
---------------------------------------------------------------
 0.2=0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
+0.2=0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
---------------------------------------------------------------
 0.4=0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625

==============================================================
Answer
--------------------------------------------------------------
  0.4=0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
==0.4=0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. **[Source:Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)**
2. **[Source:Why 0.1 Does Not Exist In Floating-Point](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)**
3. [Further Guide About Float Point](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
4. [Guide By Oricle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
5. [Examine Number](http://www.panojohnson.com/automatons/floating-point-1.xhtml)
6. [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: I didn't downvote this (yet), but I love these images from [Rick Regan's article](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/). Oh, and link 1 is broken.

Comment: Answers shouldn't  be plagiarized, you should give credit where it is due

Comment: What does this long post even say? Where in all this do you mention that floating point numbers are inaccurate? Also note that plagiarism (posting other people's work as your own answer without attribution) [isn't acceptable and your answer can get flagged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered). Put the links to your sources

Comment: These edits IMHO saved your post (upvoted). It would be nice if you add something (including references) to [UNUM](http://sites.ieee.org/scv-cs/files/2013/03/Right-SizingPrecision1.pdf) as a possible future solution.

Comment: A simple link to Rick Regan's blog would do, you are not improving the Internet by copying it here as screenshots. The question you are answering has been answered already and your answer does not make this site better. Downvoted.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It means I must not give "Refined answer" of any question
 while Compleate Answer is not given in a single post